Spring Cloud Config Server Not Fetching Service-Specific Properties
I'm having an issue with my Spring Cloud Config setup. I have the following configurations:
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths={application}/{profile},common/{profile},{application},common

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true

logging.level.org.springframework.cloud=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

When I request properties for authentication-service with the local profile using the following URL:
GET http://localhost:8081/authentication-service/local

I only receive the common properties and not the service-specific properties from authentication-service-security.properties.
What I've Tried

Verified the repository structure and file permissions.
Checked the config server logs for any errors or warnings.
Disabled caching by setting spring.cloud.config.server.git.refreshRate=0.
Manually cloned the repository to ensure the files are accessible and correctly formatted.

Could anyone help me identify what might be going wrong or suggest additional steps to troubleshoot this issue?
